# Android: One panel on top of another in the same Parent panel

Tags: android, android-layout

Sorry if the question has been already asked & answered, I was searching the DB without success. (Updated see the end).

I have a Parent layout panel A. In that A I need to have another two layout panels B and C. B and C should be "Docked" inside A the same way, but in code I will set Visibility to B and C during runtime, depending on some internal conditions, to show user B or C.

How should I set that layouts in the activity XML file?

The image is attached and you'll have two panels black and grey (B and C), they compete for space in Parent A, but they have to be one on top of another one. And also I paste the xml structure of the controls - child Relative = B and TableLayout = C.

I am newbie in Android, but good enough in C#..

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:context="ru.itbrigada.satcli.SatCli"
    android:background="#3e657f">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/helloScreen"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/controlDarkDark"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:background="@drawable/delete" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="№XX"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="@dimen/abc_action_bar_stacked_max_height" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"></TableLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="0" android:background="@color/white" android:layout_height="60dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:id="@+id/photo" />

            <TextClock
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/timePassed"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Вопрос 1 из 10"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:typeface="sans" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/finish_test"
                android:id="@+id/finishTest"
                android:background="@drawable/blueback"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

UPD: I know that the Views (Controls) like TextView Button, they could be overlapped, then maybe there is a way to create "UserControl" with the same behaviour as TextView and Button?

Also, maybe the Tabhost container? With hidden Tabs child(0)? Would I be able to switch them (tab panes) from code?

Comment: Please can you show how do you like your layout to look?

Comment: I don't know how to show it.. it's like a sandwich panel... you set one visible, another invisible, then vice versa. Split them.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: use FrameLayouts for each of the panels

Comment: @Aalap Patel, "each of the panel" .. do you mean B and C?

Comment: whichever you want to overlap..

Comment: FrameLayout blocks full screen.. it is not what I need.

Comment: @VitaliPetrov Do you want the layout B to appear over layout C, overlapping it completely?

Comment: yes.. I am considering TabHost, but still without success yet